# int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java

```
int i = 0;
String[] b = new String[]{releaseId, i});
```

causes an `int cannot be converted to java.lang.String`

From what I know java does implicit String conversion (in case of non-primitives a call to toString()) ?

So what is wrong here?

Is there something different about Java for Android?!

Comment: int i = 0; String[] b = new String[]{""+releaseId, ""+i});

Comment: ^ Please don't do that - That is really not good practice - yes it works but you should use `String.valueOf();`

Comment: @Ed George that was the reason why I post it as comment and not answer. of course you are right.

Answer (score 8):

> From what I know java does implicit String conversion (in case of
>   non-primitives a call to toString()) ? So what is wrong here?

That's true for objects. int is a primitive type not an object.

Use `String.valueOf(i)` to retrieve the String representation of `i`

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Java doing implicit `String` conversion for Objects, not for primitive types.

You need to use `Integer` or `String.valueOf(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 "good" ways to convert an integer to a String. `Integer.toString(i)` or `String.valueOf(i)`.

It is possible to do something like this `String s = "" + i;` but that is considered a bad smell.